# Что с винтом? Диагностика говорит, что всё ОК

Tags: железо, hdd

Имеется HDD на 500 Гб WD. Суть проблемы в том, что постоянно слетает система. постоянно то синий экран, то слетает так, что вообще только восстановление системы помогает. 
Что знаю точно:

- Это именно винт, а не память / мат. плата и пр. Поставил другой винт, всё работает без сбоев.
- Это не система. Дистрибутив проверенный, на других HDD работает без проблем.
- Это не кабель SATA. Пробовал разные.

Как только заполучил сей экземпляр, сразу сделал тест поверхности Викторией. Вылезли 2 бэд-блока, с коими случился Remap.

**А вот дальше самое интересное**. Система продолжает слетать, а последующие тесты поверхности не выявляют никаких повреждённых блоков и даже медленных!
Тестировал поверхность уже 3-мя программами:

- Victoria (и из по DOS и из под Windows PE)
- MHDD
- родная утилита от WD

Вот S.M.A.R.T сего экземпляра:
[image: Скриншот с параметрами SMART]

Возникают вопросы:

1. Если bad-блоки реально были и с ними произошёл remap, почему
   параметры SMART №5 и №196 = 0?
2. Если это были софтовые bad-блоки, почему винт продолжает глючить? Как с этим бороться?
3. Может это электроника? Или контакты шлейфа от платы к корпусу?
4. Напрягает, что параметры 198-200 красным цветом. Но они вроде как на здоровье винта не влияют.

Посторонних звуков винт не издаёт.
В чём может быть дело?

Тест скорости (случайное заполнение):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Контакты почистил. Да они все и были чистые. Ещё момент: в Victoria параметр 198 Offline scan UNC sectors (количество выявленных ошибочных секторов электроникой диска) в программе Crystal Disk Info - это параметр C6 и называется "Неисправимые ошибки секторов". Наводит на мысль. При этом переназначенных нет.

Мне кажется, что всё-таки сбойные сектора есть, но электроника винта не хочет это признавать и не производит переназначений.

Comment: Добавь тесты скорости, особенно с радномным позиционированием.

Comment: UDMA CRC Errors >> 0  - это вроде как примера битого шлейфа / контактов

Comment: Чуть позже выложу тест скорости. Также хочу посмотреть состояние шлейфа от электроники к корпусу. Где-то читал, что там если контакты почистить, может помочь.

Comment: Просто бракованный диск. Такое бывает с б/у дисками - а б/у они становятся после первого включения.

Comment: есть мысль, что это контроллер/разъем.